# Encapsulation levels in Java Enterprise Project

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, maven, jakarta-ee

I am working on an enterprise level project. DB is in MySQL and project uses Maven, Hibernate and Spring MVC. I've gotten through defining the data models now I need to start implementation.

My question is, is it better to create the service and implementation layers in separate projects or should they be in the same project as the data model layer? What are the pros and cons and how should I go about it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just a web app and you won't share any code with other applications, then just put entities in one package, controllers in another package and so on. No need to create multiple projects. If your application is going really big or you have to share code with other projects, then you can think of separating.